# Angularjs ng-repeat Array vs Object

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat, json

I am using ng-repeat to display data in a View coming from an endpoint in a form of atom feed. This endpoint returns JSON if Accept header is 'application/json', that JSON is created from XML on a server-side by an converter, unfortunately if there is one entry in the atom response then the entry in the JSON is not an array and ng-repeat does not work as expected. I had a project where I handled this manually by using a counter and then based on that counter and ng-show I either used ng-repeat or just displayed the single entry from the feed. How do I handle this correctly? Should I rework the incoming JSON on JS side? If yes could someone point me the right way of doing that.

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
 <id>/record</id>
 <title type="text">Search feed</title>
 <link href="/record" rel="self"/>
 <link href="/record?page=2" rel="next"/>
 <entry>
    <id>recordid</id>
    <link href="/record/id/recordid" rel="self"/>
    <content type="recordcontenttype">
        <record>...recordhere...</record>
    </content>
 </entry>
</feed>

{
"feed": {
    "entry": 
        {
            "content": {
                ...recordhere...
                },
                "type": "recordcontenttype"
            },
            "id": "recordid",
            "link": {
                "href": "/record/id/recordid",
                "rel": "self"
            }
        },

        -- if there would be more entries then entry would be an array [ { xx }, { xx } ] and ng-repeat would work --

    "id": "/record",
    "link": [
        {
            "href": "/record",
            "rel": "self"
        },
        {
            "href": "/record?page=2",
            "rel": "next"
        }
    ],

    "title": {
        "content": "Search feed",
        "type": "text"
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a simple filter, e.g.:

```js
(function (app, ng) {
  'use strict';

  app.controller('AppCtrl', function AppCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    
    vm.foo = { id: 1 };
    vm.bar = [{ id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];
  });


  app.filter('ensureArray', function () {
    return function (input) {
      return ng.isArray(input) ? input : [input];
    };
  })
}(angular.module('app', []), angular));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
  <div data-ng-repeat="foo in app.foo|ensureArray">
    {{ foo|json }}
  </div>

  <div data-ng-repeat="bar in app.bar|ensureArray">
    {{ bar|json }}
  </div>
</div>
```